# How do I determine the "length" of this derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear

What length is this derailleur please. Cannot determine if its a short, medium or long.

[image: close-up photograph of Shimano Tourney rear derailleur]

Comment: Not on the side: The derailleur cable is way too long, bout 4-5cm. There's a strong risk of it getting sucked into the cage between the chain and the low jockey wheel.

Comment: FWIW, Most brands measure the derailleur cage length as the distance between the  center of the jockey wheels. On a side note is that a cable coming out of the axle?

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot like the Shimano [TY-300-SGS](https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/product/component/tourney/RD-TY300-SGS.html) on the product page, which would be a long cage rear derailleur.

However there's no strict guarantee that the current derailleur is the best one for the job, and the definition of short, medium, long changes with time. There are other specs on the product page, like total capacity, low sprocket min/max, etc, which you can check are suitable for your gearing. Sometimes it's better to check the specs first rather than just choose medium or long.

You might find that you could select a shorter length cage for your needs, which could give better ground clearance with those small wheels, for example.